# Can I install a PC-MAC DVD Rom application on Ubuntu 12.04LTS?

Tags: installation, mac

I bought by mistake a collection of sceneries for XPlane (Fligh Sim) but I didn't realise these DVDs are for PC and Mac only. Is there a way to install them on Ubuntu anyway? Thanks for your patience, I am a noobie ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it with `wine`:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

It can run Windows software on linux, but it doesen't work with all software.
Give it a try and report any problems, maybe someone can help.

Comment: thanks for you help. I installed Wine and Virtual Machine as well but it seems I'm not even able to run those 2 apps! I am very new to Ubuntu just installed last week...